# Express rest api get all endpoints

Tags: node.js, api, rest, express

I have nodejs app with express framework. If I want to catch all endpoints for a http method, say 'GET', how would I define it. I tried :

```
app.get('*', ... )
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I don't want to use 'ALL' , just specific method.

Comment: Note that routes are matched in order. Is this placed before any other routes that may match the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know you should use:

```
app.get('/*',.......)
```

Answer (score 0):

try using for get method

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) { ... });
```

or use this for all methods

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) { ... });
```